# Entities created instead of linked in CollectionType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem with one of my forms. The form has to create a new Colle entity and link some other Colle entities to it.
When I submit it, a new entity is created for each item in collesEnfants collection field. The new entity created is correctly linked to the parent and has the right 'ordre' field but it's a newly created entity and not the entity I've selected.

My form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom', TextType::class,['label' => 'Nom de la colle'])
    ->add('collesEnfants', CollectionType::class,
        ['label' => false,
        'entry_type' => SousColleFormType::class,
        'required' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Colle'
    ]);
}
```

SousColleFormType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('matiere', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Matiere',
            'attr' => ['class'=> 'matiere'],
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une matière',
            'mapped' => false])
        ->add('nom', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'colles'],
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'label' => false,
            'group_by' => 'matiere',
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'choose.colle'])
        ->add('ordre', IntegerType::class,[
            'attr'=>['class'=>'ordre'],
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Colle'
    ]);
}
```

Controller :

```
$formColleMere = $this->createForm(AjoutSuperColleFormType::class, $colle);
    $formColleMere->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Créer']);

    $formColleMere->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formColleMere->isSubmitted() && $formColleMere->isValid()) {

        $collesEnfants = $formColleMere->get('collesEnfants')->getData();
        foreach ($collesEnfants as $enfant) {
            $colle->addColleEnfant($enfant);
        }

        if (!$colle->getCollesEnfants()->isEmpty()) {
            $em->persist($colle);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

Colle entity :

```
class Colle
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Colle", mappedBy="colleMere", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "asc"})
 */
private $collesEnfants;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Colle", inversedBy="collesEnfants", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="colleMere_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $colleMere;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $nom;

{........}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Matiere", inversedBy="colles", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="matiere_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $matiere;

/**
 * Cet attribut sert aux 'super colles' qui sont le résultat d'une fusion de colles d'une même UE
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="ordre", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $ordre;
```

Comment: `$collesEnfants = $formColleMere->get('collesEnfants')->getData();` i don't even see that defined in your form...are you sure you've given the current code?  also you shouldn't even need that `foreach` if you've probably defined your associations and form type

Comment: collesEnfants is defined in the first form. It's the field containing the Collection. I know I shouldn't need the foreach but I tried many things and it's still not working as it should

Comment: Oh oops sorry I didn't see that. I'll try to have a closer look later

Comment: @JasonRoman  Did you have some time to look at my problem ?

Comment: Sorry forgot about it...I'll look in the morning

Comment: It seems like with this form you're not actively selecting other Colle entities for CollesEnfants.  Like, you're entering completely new data in your SousColleFormType, not selecting existing Colle entities.

Comment: With this collection, I have fields which allows me to select other Colle entities. Do you know what I have to change to link Colle entities I select in the CollesEnfants Collection to the main Colle entity I create with the parent form and set  `ordre` property to what's typed in ordre field for each of collesEnfants?

Comment: It depends.  It seems like you might want a collection of EntityType fields that link, and then have a separate `ordre` property you set after.  Off the top of my head that might work...but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in doing what I want by adding `'mapped' => false` to collesEnfants field. 
I also changed these lines in the Controller :

```
$collesEnfants = $formColleMere->get('collesEnfants')->getData();
foreach ($collesEnfants as $enfant) {
   $colle->addColleEnfant($enfant);
}
```

To :

```
$collesEnfants = $formColleMere->get('collesEnfants')->getData();

foreach ($collesEnfants as $enfant) {
    $colle->addColleEnfant($enfant['nom']);
    $enfant['nom']->setOrdre($enfant['ordre']);
}
```